# Titanium android external intent to specific app

Tags: android, android-intent, titanium, titanium-alloy

I want to open an Android app from a Titanium one with an`Explicit intent`and send a string to it.

i tried the following examples but none of it is working.

```
var intent = Ti.Android.createIntent({
                        action: Ti.Android.ACTION_DEFAULT,
                        packageName:"com.example.new_pdf_reader"
                       //url:"com.example.new_pdf_reader"
             });
                    intent.addCategory(Ti.Android.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);
                    Ti.Android.currentActivity.startActivity(intent);
```

and

```
var shareIntent = Ti.Android.createIntent({

                                action : Ti.Android.ACTION_SEND,
                                type : "text/plain"
                        });

shareIntent.putExtra('net.sf.andpdf.extra.PDFFILENAME', "path");
Ti.Android.currentActivity.startActivity(Ti.Android.createIntent(shareIntent, "Share image"));
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My example app is : `PDF_reader`

```
 var intent = Ti.Android.createIntent({
        action: Ti.Android.ACTION_SENDTO,
        data: 'com.example.new_pdf_reader',
        type:'text/plain'
    });

    intent.addCategory(Ti.Android.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);
    intent.putExtra('net.sf.andpdf.extra.PDFFILENAME', Titanium.Filesystem.get+ '/File.pdf');

    Ti.Android.currentActivity.startActivity(intent);
```